# Find the smallest set after merging key with empty list from one dictionary with another dictionary containing that key as value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries in Python 3-x.:

```
A = {1: [9], 7: [], 14: [], 32: [9], 40: []}
```

and

```
B = {1: [7, 9, 10], 7: [1, 14], 14: [7, 40], 32: [9, 40], 40: [14, 32]}
```

I want to find, for those empty lists as values in dict A, the key, contained as values in dict B. Then, merge that key from dict A to the value list, containing the key from A and output the shortest set of combined key and value merger.

For example,
key 7 in dict A has an empty list as value. So we look, which value lists in B contains key 7. We see that 1: [7, 9, 10] and 14: [7, 40] contains "7" as value. So perform a merger to output the sets: {1, 7, 9, 10} and {14, 40, 7}. From these two sets, the final output should be the smallest set, i.e., {14, 40, 7}. Note: If both sets are same size, I would like to choose the first one.
The same goes for the keys 14 and 40 in dict A.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
temp3 = []
for k, v in A.items():
 if len(v) == 0:
       s3 = set()
       for i,j in B.items():
           if k in j:
               lst = []
               lst.append(j)
               min_list = min(lst)
               s3 = set(min_list)
               s3.add(k)
               s3.add(i)
               temp3.append(s3)
               C = set()
               for i in temp3:
                   C = set(i)
               print("temp3 for", k, "is", C)
```

The output is:

```
temp3 for 7 is {9, 1, 7, 10}
temp3 for 7 is {40, 14, 7}
temp3 for 14 is {1, 14, 7}
temp3 for 14 is {32, 40, 14}
temp3 for 40 is {40, 14, 7}
temp3 for 40 is {40, 9, 32}
```

I can perform the mergers. But I cannot figure out how to get the smallest set as output as describes above. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you use an iterable of the candidate sets and use `min` on it:

```
for a in A:
    if not A[a]:
        sets = ({b, *B[b]} for b in B if a in B[b])
        print(a, min(sets, key=len))
```

Output:

```
7 {40, 14, 7}
14 {1, 14, 7}
40 {40, 14, 7}
```